# Modify value inside href links using beautiful soup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am able to extract the 'href' but I also want to modify the values in href link.
Below is the example:-

```
Input-

    <a style="color:#85bc20" href="https://example.com?new=[sample]&hash=[hashkey]">
                                                         Unsubscribe
                                                     </a>
```

Output-

```
  <a style="color:#85bc20" href="https://example.com?new="samplevalue"&hash='123'">
                                                         Unsubscribe
                                                     </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<a style="color:#85bc20" href="https://example.com?new=[sample]&hash=[hashkey]"> Unsubscribe </a>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.find_all('a'):
  a['href'] = a['href'].replace("[sample]", "samplevalue").replace('[hashkey]', "123")
```

Result `print(soup.prettify(formatter=None))`:

```
<a href="https://example.com?new=samplevalue&hash=123" style="color:#85bc20"> Unsubscribe </a>
```